# C++ Static variable inside function cannot be changes

Tags: c++, static, constants, variable-assignment, redeclaration

Can someone please explain to me the following.

`static_outer` works as expected. When the `print_str()` function is called, `static_outer` is assigned the value from the parameter and then printed to output.

`static_inner` "misbehaves" a little. It is also assigned the value from the parameter, when the function is called. But when the function is called for the second time, the printed value is the same as in the first call.

Why doesn't the assignment change the value? My only intuition is that the line is ignored because the `static_inner` is already declared but compiler does not complain.

```
static const char* static_outer;

void print_str(const char* const str) {

    static const char* static_inner = str; 
    cout << static_inner << "\r\n";
    
    static_outer = str;
    cout << static_outer << "\r\n";
}

int main() {    
    const char str1[] = "Foo";
    const char str2[] = "Bar";

    cout << "First call" << "\r\n";
    print_str(str1);
    
    cout << "\r\n" << "Second call" << "\r\n";
    print_str(str2);
}

// Output:
// First call
// Foo
// Foo
//
// Second call
// Foo <--- this is the line in question... why not "Bar"?
// Bar
```

Live demo: https://onlinegdb.com/-OnqgsLTn

Comment: `static` has completely different meaning depending on the scope it is used at (i.e. whether it is used inside a function definition, a class definition, or at namespace scope). Don't assume they have in any way similar meaning. What you see here is exactly the behavior that `static` _inside functions_ should have. Also, are you sure you know what `static` at namespace scope will do?

Comment: The whole idea of a function local static is that it retains its value between calls. If it was "reinitialized" every time, how would that work? I'm guessing you assume `=` is assignment, but that is a common pitfall in C and C++, for it is used both in assignment and initialization (and this here is the latter).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica yup, that was the problem. I did not realize that `=` can be interpreted in different ways. Can you confirm that I got the following right... 1) `static` outside function or class is accessible within the file (comp. unit) and is common for the whole file. 

2) `static` inside function is accessible only inside that function but its lifetime spans all calls of that function. 

3) The `static` declaration in subsequent function call are just ignored completely by the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My only intuition is that the line is ignored because the `static_inner` is already declared

Your intuition is correct, that is exactly what happens. You are assigning the `str` parameter to `static_inner` in its declaration. A `static` local variable is initialized only one time, the first time the function is called. On subsequent calls, the variable retains its previous value. That is the whole point of declaring a local variable as `static`.

To do what you want, you need to separate the static local variable's declaration from its assignment, eg:

```
static const char* static_inner;
static_inner = str;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, accepted .
I would add that it is important (in C++) to distinguish between assignment and initialization, which are both depicted by "=" sign. Initialization (when you declare type) happens only once, assignment every time.

Answer (score 2):

Once a function static variable is initialized, the line `static const char* static_inner = str;` has no further effects.

If you want the variable to change every time it is called, you would need to have a line of code performing assignment:

```
void print_str(const char* const str) {

    static const char* static_inner;
    static_inner = str;
    cout << static_inner << "\r\n";
    
    static_outer = str;
    cout << static_outer << "\r\n";
}
```